# vim: Use different colorscheme when connected over SSH

Tags: ssh, vim, colors

On my desktop I use the [hbrid color scheme](https://github.com/w0ng/vim-hybrid) in vim, with the preferred colors set for my consoles 16-color palette (as described in the README).

However, on my laptop, I use the solarized color scheme, so when I SSH into my desktop from my laptop and open VIM it will look funny using the hybrid colors.

Is there any way I can 'forward' a vim configuration to set the colors when SSHing into a different machine? (Assume the colorscheme file is already installed, and all that needs to be done is call `colorscheme solarized`)

Answer (score 7):

You can access environment variables [in your `vimrc` using `$NAME`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#expand-env). `ssh` sets the environment variable [`SSH_CONNECTION` within an SSH session](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1#x454e5649524f4e4d454e54) to non-empty metadata about the connection. You can combine these two to run configuration code based on whether you're accessing `vim` over SSH or not:

```
if $SSH_CONNECTION
    colorscheme solarized
endif
```

The body of the `if` runs when `SSH_CONNECTION` is non-empty, so if you put this into your desktop's `.vimrc` then you'll get the solarized theme over SSH, and whatever you configured earlier the rest of the time.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Good solution, this works well for when I only have two color configurations. But lets say I have another machine that uses a different terminal color scheme that I want to enable when SSHing into my desktop. I see the `SSH_CONNECTION` identifies the client. But only the local IP. perhaps there is a way to pass some kind of identifying information with the SSH connection?

Comment: I could enable `AcceptEnv` in sshd on my desktop. But I was hoping to be able to use this kind of setup for other machines where I may not be able to configure `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: There is a `-o SendEnv=VARNAME` option you can use to pass a local variable to the destination, which must be enabled on the server. Alternatively, `ssh -t hostname env VAR=value bash -i` will set the `VAR` variable and run a login shell. `TERM` is also passed through by default, but it takes some work to store something useful there.

Comment: Brilliant! Solves a problem that's annoyed me for a while